# Best Practise to provide User-Configuration for an VSTS-Extension

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I'm developing a VSTS-Extension which will be executable in the contextmenu of a workitem. I need to provide user-level configuration for the action that is performed by the extension (e.g. which external service should be notified, when performing an action). I'll store the data using the Data-Service provided by the API.

Is there a best-practise to make the configuration available to the user (comparable to the configuration of a dashboard-widget)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn’t the configuration view to config context menu of a work item extension.

You can configure it in a [backlog tab page](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-backlog-tabs) and store the settings for the user by using [Data Storage](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/data-storage).